# How to changed Encrypted data to Decrypted in Sql server

Tags: sql-server

I try more time to change in sql, encrypted data to decrypted..
 Anybody know this solution,pls reply me..

my password shown as this format 0C6EB14DB9C05361B517EA553E77C977
but datatype was varchar

I want to need to encrypt this data

Comment: 1) How was it encrypted? 2) If it's a one way encryption (called a hash), you're out of luck. Those aren't reversible*. *Unless it's un-salted and you consult a rainbow table for the hash algorithm to see if your password hash is in it anywhere. Or if it's an outdated hash, such as md5, and you bruteforce it until you get it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using [PWDENCRYPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822791%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to encrypt your data. If so, then it is impossible to recover you password, because is makes a hash so you cannot reverse the hashed string. It is the idea of the hash algorithm to make it impossible. If you want to compare your input values with your encrypted values you can use [PWDCOMPARE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822792.aspx) function.